# Yii inner join with CActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii

> How can run this query on yii by using CActiveDataProvider.
>
> select co.name,re.company_id,re.person_name,re.last_login_at, (select
>   count(*) from activity_logs ac where re.id = ac.user_id ) as count
>   from companies co inner join employers re on co.id = re.company_id
>   limit 20;

Recruiter relation

> ```
> public function relations()
> {
>     // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
>     // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
>     return array(
>         'candidatesEmployers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CandidatesEmployers', 'employer_id'),
>         'employerCandidateActivities' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'EmployerCandidateActivities', 'employer_id'),
>         'city' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Cities', 'city_id'),
>         'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Companies', 'company_id'),
>         'interviews' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Interviews', 'employer_id'),
>         'jobs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Jobs', 'employer_id'),
>     );
> }
> ```

Companies relations

> ```
> public function relations()
> {
>   // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
>   // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
>   return array(
>       'city' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Cities', 'city_id'),
>       'employers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Employers', 'company_id'),
>   );
> }
> ```

ActivityLogs relations

> ```
> public function relations()
> {
>   // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
>   // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
>   return array(
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

use this method may help you ;)
your code is so big for attection ..Write a simplest part ...

```
$topRage=new CDbCriteria();
$topRage->select="*";
$topRage->alias="re";
$topRage->order="rateing DESC";
$topRage->join='JOIN co ON co.id = re.company_id';
$topRage->limit="20";



$my = yourMODELnAME::model()->findAll($topRage);


foreach($my as $a){
   echo $a->....
}
```